# Undefined variable object using Underscore JS partials and for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I'm writing a twitter aggregator and I need some help on solving the error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: sqTweetData is not defined.' It looks like console is pointing me to my for loop. I have set up a partial that is compiled and loaded in #main-content using underscore js.

For Loop Code

```
<!-- Main Content -->
<main class="main">
    <div class="container-flex" id="main-content"></div>
</main> <!-- End Main Content -->

<!-- Current Tweet Partials -->
<script id="active-tweet-partial" type="underscore/template">
    <section class="tweetFlexItem">

    <% for (var i = 0; i < sqTweetData.length; i++) { %>
        <div class="activeTweet">
            <div class="activeTweet__avatar"><img src="<%= sqTweetData[ i ].user.profile_image_url %>"></div>
            <div class="activeTweet__wrapper">
                <div class="activeTweet__name"> <%= sqTweetData[ i ].user.name %> </div>
                <div class="activeTweet__message"><%= sqTweetData[ i ].text %></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% } %>

    </section>
</script>
```

home.js Compiling Code

```
var Home = (function() {

var sqTweetData = {
    user: [{
        profile_image_url : "assets/avatar.png",
        name : "@johnsnow"
    }],
    text : "Someone once said that I know nothing..."
};

console.log("this is sqTweetData", sqTweetData);

// Partials
var tweetPartial = $('#active-tweet-partial').html();
    tweetPartialCompiled = _.template( tweetPartial );

// DOM Handlers

// KICKSTART VIEW
function initHome() {

    // load main content
    $('#main-content').html(tweetPartialCompiled( sqTweetData ));

    // bind events

}
return {
    init: initHome
};

})();
```

The console.log on line 11 works just fine, so I'm assuming my variable object is set up correctly. There just seems to be a disconnect between the partial and the rest of the javascript.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You're trying to access a variable that doesn't exist. The variable was declared in `Home` not in the global `window`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a scoping issue. `sqTweetData` says it's undefined because it's exactly that. `window["sqTweetData"]` does not exist. When you declare a variable outside of a function it's inserted into the global namespace, in this case the browser `window` is the namespace.

Since you're declaring the variable inside of home using the `var` keyword, the variable will only be accessible **within** the `Home` function. So you'd have to add it as either a `this.sqTweetdata` and return it with the object, or add a separate `getTweetData()` that return the variable, or something along those lines.

Check out this answer that covers scoping very comprehensively:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/500459/3629438

Yours falls under:

**Advanced: Closure**

```
var a = 1;

var six = (function() {   

  var a = 6;

  return function() {
    // JavaScript "closure" means I have access to 'a' in here,
    // because it is defined in the function in which I was defined.
    alert(a);   
  }; 
})();
```

---

**EDIT:**

In your case you would do something along the lines of

```
var Home = (function() {

// ....... //    

function getTweetData() {
   return sqTweetData;
}
return {
    init: initHome,
    get: getTweetData
};

})();
```

Comment: Awesome, totally makes sense. How would I go about create a getTweetData() function to pass the data for global use?

Comment: I think `tweetPartialCompiled({ sqTweetData: sqTweetData})` would be a more appropriate solution in the context of an Underscore template. Underscore mangles the template into a JavaScript function and uses [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) to alter the scoping rules.

Comment: @muistooshort ah you are correct, I'm not as well versed in Underscore however and was answering from a standpoint of vanilla javascript